# Trying to patch areas of drywall texture

Tags: drywall, texture

Can someone please help me identify this type of drywall texture and maybe give me some tips for how to match it.  I’ve got a few areas where I’ve patched and I’m not finding anything online to help me figure out what style this is or how to try and match it. I’d roughly guess it’s just some sort of skip-trowel but don’t want to make it ugly or spend all day trying to match it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiVSX.jpg[image]

Comment: It is skip trowel. I find it incredibly hard to match these sorts of things. Best advice is to use topping compound (easier to sand) and have a sponge at the ready to remove an attempt that you hate.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept.

Comment: An image containing a reference to size would be helpful - i.e tape some currency to the wall.

Comment: I’ve added a photo with scale reference.  The smaller blobs are more typical of the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

That looks somewhat like a "knock down" texture. The ceilings in my house look like this:

[image]

This type of texture can take on many variations of look which can depend on the consistency of the mud when it was spattered on, type of spray gun and nozzle used and how long the material has dried before you knock it down with a knock down tool or other wide drywall knife.

I had only moderate success trying to re-texture a bathroom where I had to open the ceiling to install some electrical wiring years back. I tried some of those spatter spray cans of texture that you can buy at the big box stores. My results after several practice sessions on scrap drywall were less than spectacular.

More recently I was trying to deal with matching a ceiling in a laundry room where about a third of the ceiling needed to be replaced with new drywall. Based upon my previous experience in that bathroom and the discussion on [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/189618/7367) I decided to just skim coat the whole thing and leave texturing to the paint roller when installing the paint.

Comment: That is close.   I would have referred him to your question about 1/4" drywall.

Comment: @DMoore - Notice the underlined "this question" in the last sentence of my answer. That is a link that I put there when I wrote the answer yesterday.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and be ready to wipe off (patches are just couple square feet, so relatively small) if I don’t like how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

To me that looks like the texture gun was set on large splatter and knocked down with a wide knife, almost impossible to match , I have found getting in the ballpark on the repair then adding a light coat of orange peak over the entire room it helps to blend everything and drywall mud is cheap.

This assumes you have an air compressor and a mud gun can be purchased for ~ 50$ , they are cheap plastic and if well cleaned after you may get a few uses. 
Adding water to standard joint compound setting the gun and shooting an area to get close let it sit for a few minutes then knock it down, you can try on a piece of scrap or even a wall that has a smooth area, not right use mud knife scrape it off very easy for ~20 minutes. Once you get it right let it dry clean the gun, the next day set the gun for a small spatter cover the entire room clean the gun. 
Never use a setting or Hot mud with a gun it can ruin the gun even a pro model, and if the vent plugs a “sealed” hopper can explode if the small vent gets plugged. Just don’t use hot mud.

This is how I cover remodel patches that I can’t match and it is just about impossible to see the repair.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestions.  Adding orange peel to room wouldn’t be practical since it’s in hallway and entire house is same texture.

Comment: If you read my advice a heavy knock down after a repair is IMPOSSIBLE to hide so I do my best and then an orange peak over the top and not even I can find the repair I did not do.